# How to best implement a log in page with Caliburn.Micro MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am new to using caliburn.micro and currently learning MVVM.

I am using the windows template studio to create my UWP app, and it works great! But unfortunately, I am not familiar with MVVM and still learning UWP.

I get how the navigation works etc and how the shellpage is loaded. However, I want to prompt the user to log in upon opening the app (i.e. a login in page will start with no navigation sidebar).

I also want to make sure I'm following best practices...

I have tried substituting the MainViewModel with LoginViewModel which I get works, however, I don't want to create the navigation pane. I get that this is triggered by the "new Lazy(CreateShell)". I'm just not sure if I want to remove this from the activation service and call a method upon login?

Below is the default code supplied by the windows template studio which triggers on activation of the app if I understand correctly.

```
private ActivationService CreateActivationService()
    {
        return new ActivationService(_container, typeof(ViewModels.LoginViewModel), new Lazy<UIElement>(CreateShell));
    }

private UIElement CreateShell()
    {
        var shellPage = new Views.ShellPage();
        _container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IConnectedAnimationService), nameof(IConnectedAnimationService), new ConnectedAnimationService(shellPage.GetFrame()));
        return shellPage;
    }
```

I just need to be pointed in the right direction or lead to a video/tutorial as I'm struggling!!! any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show login page,you can remove the ShellPage.It is a navigation view.

in App.xaml.cs

```
private ActivationService CreateActivationService()
        {​
            return new ActivationService(this, typeof(LoginPage));​
        }​
​
private UIElement CreateShell()​
        {​
            return new Views.ShellPage();​
        }
```

When login successfully,if you want to show the navigation view,you can set the ShellPage to the content of current window.

```
Window.Current.Content = new Views.ShellPage();
```